# Why does this while loop in C not print my first input alongside the rest of the output?

Tags: c, while-loop, output

I've made an alarm clock in C that asks the user for the current time and alarm time as HHMMSS. It splits these into hours, minutes and seconds, before looping starting from the current time input, until the alarm time input, when it prints "ALARM" instead of the time. The problem is that the output skips the current time input, starting one second after it instead. See input and output below:

```
What time is it? (HHMMSS)
235958
When should the alarm go? (HHMMSS)
000003
________
23:59:59
00:00:00
00:00:01
00:00:02
ALARM
```

But the output I want is:

```
23:59:58  
23:59:59
00:00:00
00:00:01
00:00:02
ALARM
```

I've looked at the while loops, changing the three `printf("%02d:%02d:%02d \n", present_hour, present_minute, present_second);` statements to each have different things between the numbers, so one of them had colons, the other semicolons and the last one hyphens. Doing this and trying different inputs showed me that each while loop has the same problem of skipping the current time in the output. I'm assuming this means that the mistake lies in the shared code each of the loops have. I'd guess something could be wrong with the condition of the loops and/or the first if statement in each, but if that's the case I don't get *why* it ignores the current time input in the output.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int present_time, time_for_alarm;
int present_hour, present_minute, present_second;
int alarm_hour, alarm_minute, alarm_second;

void update_time();

int main()
{
    input_time();
    update_time(present_time, time_for_alarm);
    return 0;
}

void input_time(int present_time, int time_for_alarm)  
{                                                     
    printf("What time is it now? (HHMMSS) \n");
    scanf("%d", &present_time);
    while(present_time > 235959 || present_time < 0){
    printf("Invalid time. What time is it now? (HHMMSS) \n");
    scanf("%d", &present_time);
    }
    
    printf("When should the alarm go? (HHMMSS) \n");
    scanf("%d", &time_for_alarm);
    while(time_for_alarm > 235959 || time_for_alarm < 0){ 
    printf("Invalid time. When should the alarm go? \n");
    scanf("%d", &time_for_alarm);
    }
    
    printf("________ \n");
    
    update_time(present_time, time_for_alarm);
    printf("ALARM");

}

void update_time(int present_time, int time_for_alarm)
{   
    int present_hour = present_time/10000;
    int present_minute = (present_time/100)%100;
    int present_second = present_time%100; 
    int alarm_hour = time_for_alarm/10000;
    int alarm_minute = (time_for_alarm/100)%100;
    int alarm_second = time_for_alarm%100;
    
    while(present_hour != alarm_hour){
    if(present_hour == alarm_hour && present_minute == alarm_minute &&  present_second == alarm_second){
            printf("ALARM");
        }
    else{
            if(present_second < 60){
                present_second++;
                
        if(present_second == 60) {
            present_second = 0;
                present_minute++;
        }
        if(present_minute == 60){
            present_minute = 0 ;
            present_hour++;
        }
        if(present_hour == 24){
            present_hour = 0;
        }
        printf("%02d:%02d:%02d \n", present_hour, present_minute, present_second);
                    
            }
        }
    }
    while(present_minute != alarm_minute){
    if(present_hour == alarm_hour && present_minute == alarm_minute &&  present_second == alarm_second){
        printf("ALARM");
    }
    else{
        if(present_second < 60){
        present_second++;
                
        if(present_second == 60){
        present_second = 0;
        present_minute++;
        }
        printf("%02d:%02d:%02d \n", present_hour, present_minute,  present_second);
    
        }
    }   
}
    while(present_second != alarm_second){
    present_second++;
    if(present_hour == alarm_hour && present_minute == alarm_minute &&  present_second == alarm_second) {
        printf("ALARM");
    }
    else{      
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d \n", present_hour, present_minute,  present_second);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. Took me quite a bit to figure out why my output also included the alarm time before "ALARM", but I managed to fix that on my own. I'm definitely stuck on this one though.

Comment: Because you print the time *after* changing it?

Comment: @user253751 Just realized my while(present_second != alarm_second) loop was an old version. Apologies for that. Moving the printf statements before the time was updated at best lead to the output starting correctly, but 00:00:00 was instead skipped.

Answer (score 0):

> Moving the printf statements before the time was updated at best lead to the output starting correctly, but 00:00:00 was instead skipped.

You forgot to move *the* last `printf` to *before the time was updated*, hence *00:00:00 was* *skipped*.